# scan method doesn't work as expected

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following string:

"lotfan talash nakonid **Left** in jomalat ra bekhanid **Right** zira bi mani hastand **Right** ..."

I need to get all of the occurrences of "a set of characters followed by Left or Right". 
So for the above string I need to get the following array:

```
["lotfan talash nakonid Left", "in jomalat ra bekhanid Right", "zira bi mani hastand Right", ... ]
```

I tried to write it using scan method:

```
str.scan(/.*?(Right|Left)/) # => [["Left"], ["Right"], ["Right"]]
```

But unfortunately it seems that the parenthesis have some special meaning to `scan` method.
Is there any way we write this regexp the same way we write it in the `match` method?

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-scan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regex, you have a capture group here: `(Right|Left)`. The [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-scan) method will use the captures instead of the entire match if captures are present. You should turn `(Right|Left)` into a non-capturing group: `(?:Right|Left)`

```
str = "lotfan talash nakonid Left in jomalat ra bekhanid Right zira bi mani hastand Right ..."
str.scan(/.*?(?:Right|Left)/)
# => => ["lotfan talash nakonid Left", " in jomalat ra bekhanid Right", " zira bi mani hastand Right"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [non-capturing groups](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Grouping), like so:

```
 myString.scan(/.*?(?:Right|Left)/)
```

The [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-scan) (which I linked in a comment above) explains what is happening:

> If the pattern contains no groups, each individual result consists of the matched string, $&. If the pattern contains groups, each individual result is itself an array containing one entry per group.

Comment: You have the same answer as the one selected, but posted a little earlier, so +1. (Sorry about the mixup with the comment I deleted. I need more coffee.)

Answer (score 1):

This should accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
string.scan(/(.*?(Right|Left))/).map{|arr| arr.join(" ")}
```

The extra parentheses also capture the text before the "right" or "left".

However, the non-capturing answers are more concise and clean.

Comment: Whoops! I seem to have missed your answer, which is the same as the others, but the earliest. +1. You can get rid of the leading spaces (part of the spec) by changing your regex to `/(?<=^|\s).*?(?:Right|Left)/` or by tacking `.map(&:lstrip)` onto what you have. The latter may be better in case there are multiple spaces (and it simplifies the regex, which is always a good thing).

Comment: I missed the extra parentheses, making it a capture group, so what you get is an array of arrays, each containing one string, not what is needed.

Comment: Indeed, but a simple `.map{|arr| arr.join(' ')}` should handle that fine. The non-capturing group answers are better in that regard

Comment: Yes, but if add that to your answer it makes it a bit clunky.

Comment: Edited to get desired output